# Responsive Design with Konva?

Tags: scale, resolution

is it possible that with Konva drawed figures, dynamically scale depending of the device/resolution the user use?

So, like a responsive design?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this [example](https://coderwall.com/p/dy_dla/scale-your-kineticjs-game-dynamically) made with KineticJS and try to adapt it according to your needs. The trick is in setting a fixed size for the stage at the begining and then adapt it's size and scale accordingly to the width/height of the stage's container.

You will also have to update some naming conventions that might have changed in the transition between KineticJS and Konva.js.